# Making an infinite carousel with motion framer in react

Tags: reactjs, carousel, framer-motion

I want to make this image slider whenever I reach the last image after dragging on the last image it goes to the first image like the first image is next to last image I could make it to go first image but its goes back all the way for showing the first image.

I tried to make after dragging the last image and first image it goes to first and last image but animation is not the way I want.

For example there is a website that has the same slider that I want to do

https://www.dreamworks.com/how-to-train-your-dragon

There is section that named gallery in this site if somebody knows how to make that gallery please help me!

```js
import React, { useState ,useEffect} from "react";
import {animate, motion, useMotionValue} from "framer-motion"

export default function Gallery(){
    const Drag_buffer = 50 ;
    const [imgindex , setImageindex] =useState(0);
    const [dragging , setDragging]=useState(false);
    const dragX = useMotionValue(0);
    const onDragStart = ()=>{
        setDragging(true);
        // console.log("start");
    }
    
    const onDragEnd = ()=>{
        setDragging(false);
        const slider1 = document.querySelectorAll('.slider')
        
        const x = dragX.get();
        if (x <= -Drag_buffer   ){
            setImageindex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % Gallery.length)
            
        
        }else if ( x >= Drag_buffer){
            setImageindex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex - 1 + Gallery.length) % Gallery.length)
        }
         
    }
    console.log(imgindex);
    const Images = () =>{
        return (
            <>
                {Gallery.map((imgsrc , index)=>{
                    return(
                        <div className="bg-black">
                        <motion.div 
                        // key={index}
                        style={{
                            width:'100vw'  , 
                            marginRight:'20px' ,
                            backgroundImage :`url(${imgsrc})`,
                            backgroundSize : "cover",
                            backgroundPosition:"center",
                            backgroundRepeat : "no-repeat",
                            height : "38vw",
                            
                        }} 
                        
                        transition={{
                            type : "spring",
                            mass : 20,
                            stiffness : 2400,
                            damping : 50,
                            ease: 'linear', 
                            repeat: Infinity 
                            
                        }}
                        
                        className="aspect-video w-screen shrink-0 object-cover " >
                        
                        </motion.div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </>
        )
    }
    const Dots = ()=>{
        return(
            <div className="flex justify-center items-center gap-3 mt-4 ">
                {Gallery.map((img , idx) =>{
                    return<button key={idx}
                    onClick={()=> setImageindex(idx)}
                    className={`h-3 w-3  rounded-full bg-black transition-clor 
                    ${idx=== imgindex ? "bg-blue-900  " :"bg-gray-400"}`}
                    >
                        
                    </button>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    const Gallery = [
        "./img/gallery.jpg",
        "./img/gallery1.jpg",
        "./img/gallery2.jpg",
        "./img/gallery3.jpg",
        "./img/gallery4.jpg",
        "./img/gallery5.jpg",
        "./img/gallery6.jpg",
    ]
        return(
        
        <div className="relative  min-h-screen overflow-hidden ">
            <motion.div 
            infinit = {true}
            drag ="x"
            dragConstraints={{
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
            }}
            animate = {{
                translateX: `-${(imgindex * 102) % (Gallery.length * 102)}%`
            }}
            transition = {{
                 
                repeat: Infinity 
                            
            }}
            style={{
                x: dragX
            }}
            onDragStart={onDragStart}
            onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
            transition={{
                type : "spring",
                mass : 3,
                stiffness : 300,
                damping : 50,
            }}
            className="relative  cursor-grab items-center active:cursor-grabbing">
                <div className=" flex slider">
                    <Images />
                </div>
                
                
            </motion.div>
            {/* <Dots/> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: **first** - not "frist" ....